# I need to create an authentication for a distributor using jwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I need to create an authentication for a distributor using jwt. However I'm only able to create the authentication token for the superuser. Could someone help me create a way to authenticate the distributor?

Here are the models:

```
class Distributors(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField("Nome completo", max_length=250)
    cpf = BRCPFField("CPF")
    email = models.EmailField("Email")
    password = models.CharField("Senha", max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

authentication needs to ask for name and password

Comment: it is hard to derive the issue since you are missing some models in the code you added. What is Distributors? Is it supposed to be a User? What is TimeStampedModel? Please add more context

Comment: You can use  *djangorestframework_simplejwt* to simply add `JWT` authentication to your django project. [This tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html) will help you.